# Magnifying Lens examples using JUNG

Tags: jung

I am trying to use the JUNG library on a project.
But I am having trouble identifying if there is a simple way already to change the size of the magnifying lens on the example projects.
Currently in all the examples the magnifying lens are bounded to the size of the graph view and to the window size.
Is there a method to set only the size of the lens and break the link to the window size?
I am using the latest available JUNG version.

Thank you so much in advance!

regards,

Nelson

Comment: Right now, I just changed the ViewLensSupport constructor to accept an extra parameter for the viewRadius of the lensTransformer...

Comment: Any other way of achieving the same? I also would like to move the lens by code... :(

Answer (score 0):

The local fix that you made (adding a constructor parameter to `ViewLensSupport` to specify the lens size directly) appears to be both necessary and sufficient to fix your problem.

I agree that it makes sense to be able to control the lens size independently; feel free to send us a pull request: https://github.com/jrtom/jung/pulls

Answer (score 0):

Did you see that you can use the mouse to resize the lens by pressing and dragging on its edge? The code that is called in that case is this:

```
lensTransformer.setViewRadius(r);
```

In the edu.uci.ics.jung.samples.LensDemo, I was able to set the initial size of the lens (to 20) by modifying the code like this:

(Note that you can still use the mouse on the edge of the lens to resize it later)

```
    final JRadioButton hyperView = new JRadioButton("Hyperbolic View");
    hyperView.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            hyperbolicViewSupport.activate(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
            // added to set the lens size to 20
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                MutableTransformer mt = vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().getTransformer(Layer.VIEW);
                ((LensTransformer) mt).setViewRadius(20);
            }
        }
    });
    final JRadioButton hyperModel = new JRadioButton("Hyperbolic Layout");
    hyperModel.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            hyperbolicLayoutSupport.activate(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
            // added to set the lens size to 20
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                MutableTransformer mt = vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().getTransformer(Layer.LAYOUT);
                ((LensTransformer) mt).setViewRadius(20);
            }
        }
    });
```